# Hibernate property fetch results in ORA-01445

Tags: hibernate, oracle10g

> ORA-01445: cannot select ROWID from, or sample, a join view without a key-preserved table

I have this kind of properties in a class which set to fetch eagerly.

```
@ManyToOne(targetEntity = StudentImpl.class, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "STUDENT_ID")
private Student student;
```

But then oracle results in ORA-01445. I noticed it was because of the long select statement. When I changed to fetch attribute to lazy, no error was thrown.The Student class also has properties that eagerly fetched. I need to access the property directly without to query it again. For example `subject.getStudent()`. I am using oracle 10g version **10.1.0.4.2**.

Is it a bug on the Oracle side? Any recommendation on this issue?

thanks.

Comment: What's on the other side of the relationship and what are you trying to fetch?

Comment: Basically, getStudent() will fetch the whole column from the student table. But then student also has another complex objects which are fetch eagerly. For example getStudet().getAddress().getCountry()

Comment: It seems you can get only one row by calling getStudent()? Why it is the whole column? I think you need to put up all the mapping here otherwise others can't help you because they don't have the whole picture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is [bug in Oracle](http://www.orafaq.com/forum/?t=msg&th=11983/0/):

> Bug 4369235 ANSI joins may fail with ORA-1445
>
> Affects: Product (Component), Oracle Server (Rdbms)
>
> Range of versions believed to be affected: Versions < 11
>
> Versions confirmed as being affected:
>   9.2.0.6,
>   **10.1.0.4**,
>   10.2.0.1,
>
> Platforms affected: Generic (all / most platforms affected)
>
> Fixed: This issue is fixed in
>   9.2.0.8 (Server Patch Set),
>   10.1.0.5 (Server Patch Set),
>   10.2.0.2 (Server Patch Set), 11g
>
> Symptoms: Related To: Error May Occur ORA-1445 ANSI Joins
>
> Description: ORA-1445 can occur for ANSI join queries with large
>   views/subqueries.

Also it seems that this can happen because of another [bug in Oracle](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/21775/atypical-problem-with-ora-01445). Make sure that all tables participating in the query declare primary keys (unique constraint/index is not enough to workaround this).

So, how could you solve this? Well, as with every bug, the proper solution is to upgrade the software to a version in which the bug is fixed (here, you should upgrade the database). If this is not an option, then you don't have much choice but to accommodate your code so that it avoids using the buggy feature (change your query, mappings, etc).

For example, one of the workarounds suggested in the link I provided is to limit the number of joins to 6, so you could try to rewrite your query/mappings accordingly (you already found a similar workaround).